# I cannot access my Azure SQL database when I upload my web app using Azure Portal and devops

Tags: azure, blazor, .net-6.0

When I test my web app locally, I can access my Azure SQL database.
But when I upload my web app using the Azure Portal and Devops, the website can display, but it looks like it cannot access the Azure SQL database.

Firewall set in my SQL database of Azure portal and connection string

[image]

Firewall:

[image]

Console error...

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error it produces?

Comment: attached image of console error!

Comment: That doesn't seem as db error. Maybe is, but the main issue here is - it does not find the required endpoint, thus returns page, which is not json.

Comment: It seems  you are using private endpoints with Azure SQL. Are you uploading your Web App to an Azure App Service? If so, is it configured for VNET integration (otherwise it would not be able to connect to the private endpoint) and is it working (i.E. can you resolve the Azure SQL Name from Kudu)?